# Spring: Migrating database configuration from XML file to annotation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm trying to update my project to the newest version of Spring, Hibernate etc. and the issue I'm facing now is the migration of the database configuration from my old XML configuration file to the annotation (I really like the annotated based configuration). Below is my old configuration:

```
<!-- Configure SessionFactory -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydatabase" />
    <property name="user" value="user" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref local="dataSource" />
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.myproject.core.domain" />
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>/WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="configurationClass">
        <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref local="sessionFactory" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

<!-- END HIBERNATE CONFIG -->
```

Did any one know how to configure the sessionfactory and the transaction manager using annotations only ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I have with Hibernate 4 and spring 3.2:
You need to use [@EnableTransactionManagement](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/EnableTransactionManagement.html) for your config class.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource({ "classpath:application.properties" })
@ComponentScan({ "org.mysample.model" })
public class PersistenceConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(restDataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "org.mysample.model" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

          return sessionFactory;
     }

      @Bean
      public DataSource restDataSource() {
         BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
          dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
          dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
          dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("jdbc.username"));
          dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.password"));
          return dataSource;
       }

       @Bean
       @Autowired
       public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
          HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
          txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
          return txManager;
       }
}
```

If you need more configuration you can add them by annotating with `@Bean`. These are several dependencies including *hibernate-core:4.3.5.Final* and *javassist:3.18.1-GA*

UPDATED:
If you define some of your configurations in application.properties file, Spring automatically constructs your Datasource and other configurations:  [Common application properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)

Comment: Thank you Jama for the quick reply. I try to use as much as possible the paradigm "Convention over Configuration" to minimize the configuration. I now found out that by specifying the datasource properties in a properties file Spring will automatically create the datasource bean. So I don't need to define it anymore. Is there a similar way for the sessionFactory and the transactionManager ?

Comment: The database properties are user defined configuration, thus Spring or Hibernate cannot magically find and create datasource for you ;)

Comment: So Jama, I made Spring and Hibernate do some magic ;). I've now have a minimal configuration that seems to work well (till now). As I'm not sure if it is completely correct I'll post it down as a secondary solution. Thanks again for your answer ;)

Comment: That's great! I didn't know that after checking spring documentations, i found other properties as well: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

Answer (score 0):

Based on Jama's answer I've updated my configuration and tried to minimize it as possible. The result is a configuration class and a property file:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:/appcontext/application.properties" })
public class Application {
    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(DataSource datasource) {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(datasource);
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "org.mysample.model" });

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
        return txManager;
    }
}
```

Notes: the configuration also enables the aop supports.

the property file contains:

```
#DataSource configuration
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydatabase
spring.datasource.username=dbUsername
spring.datasource.password=dbPassword
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
```

Note: the properties file is located within the folder "/src/main/resources/appcontext/".